# Sub menu disappears on IE8

Tags: html, css, menu, internet-explorer-8, submenu

In IE8 the submenu disapears once the mouse is out of the main menu link, making it impossible to click on any item of the drop down, since the submenu immediatly disapears. I can't find out what could be wrong in my code.

CSS

```
#menu{width:978px; margin-left:0; padding-left:10px; height:40px; position:absolute; 
top:180px; height:109px; padding:3px 0 0 55px;}
#menu li{float:left; padding-top:9px; display:block;}
#menu li a{display:block; }

#menu li ul{display:none;}
#menu li:hover ul{display:block !important; position:absolute; padding-left:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:visible }
#menu li:hover li{float:none; }

.submenu{padding:0 5px 5px 5px !important; background:#ac0700; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); border:1px solid #560400; z-index:9999 !important; position:absolute; min-width:135px; margin-left:0; padding-left:0; display:block}
.submenu:hover{overflow:visible; display:block}
.submenu li a{font-size:12px; padding:6px 15px; border-right:none !important;color:#fff; padding:5px !important }
.submenu li a:hover{ background:#930600 !important; text-decoration:none !important; overflow:visible;}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="javascript: void(0)">Link</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Never never never use "!important". Read-up op how to use CSS specificity

Comment: Make sure to set your doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD xhtml 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">